# call function at specific time (specified by user) in php

Tags: php

I am creating an application in `php` in that user can send a `sms` at particular time, the time is provided by user, for example

there is text filed and time selecting option suppose user has type message and set time of monday at 5:00 pm then at monday 5:00 pm message is automatically sent

but my problem is that the time will be depend on server so how can we manage for example if user is from india and server is from U.S. then how time will be managed,

may be we can do one thing that user can select country based on that message will be sent

but how can we manage the time, do we need every second to check that and do calculation based on time?

is there any library? please, if anybody knows, then let me know

Comment: why down vote, really i do not know about this problem that why i have asked this question

Comment: please give me comment also so i can understand that my question is not proper

Comment: why are downvoted i don't know.But for your issue i think you can do it with cron job.study that

Comment: thanks Mahmood Rehman  i am just checking that :)

Answer (score 1):

u just **convert all times to the servers time** and then send messages according to it....
that is all you operations is done according to the server time only..

For eg: a user specifies 5:00 pm for india u just convert the time to its appropriate server time and just do the processing.....

Comment: ya @renishar but there might be library that can handle all this things

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to Run CRON JOB,

You Can Set the CRON JOB from C-Panel; the "CRON INTERVAL TIME" os depends on requirement, for example u may need to run it for every 5 min or 10 min .....

Now, what you need to do is take the input value from user and Save  in Server time.

then create one php file (ex:cron.php) and erite the logic there like, check the recoreds in DB which are fallen under "current tim"e and "current time - CRON INTERVAL TIME", So it will fetch the records which are to be schedule to sent on that particular time.